# Array of pointers with values of another Array of pointers - strange behavior -

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

I've got a strange situation here. I'll describe the scope and context.

File A.c

```
/*structs declared as extern in header file */
(struct) strXP A_01 = {values...};
(struct) strXP A_02 = {values...};
(struct) strXP A_03 = {values...};
(struct) strXP A_04 = {values...};
```

File B.c

```
    /*structs declared as extern in header file */
    (struct) strXP B_01 = {values...};
    (struct) strXP B_02 = {values...};
    (struct) strXP B_03 = {values...};
    (struct) strXP B_04 = {values...};
```

File C.c

```
strXP * arr_01[4] = {&A_01, &A_02, &B_01, &B_02};
strXP * arr_02[4] = {&A_03, &A_04, &B_03, &B_04};

void receive_array(strXP arr_received[], int size)
{
   for(int io = 0; io < size; io++)
   {
      strXP * const current = &arr_received[io];
      etc...
   }
}

Main_Loop:
    
    receive_array(*arr_01, 4);
```

However, during the debugger mode in function receive_array the "current" receives the following values:

```
step 01: current equals the values of A_01
step 02: current equals the values of A_02
step 03: current equals the values of A_03 (Expected was B_01)
step 04: current equals the values of A_04 (Expected was B_02)
```

Due to that, the values are updated in the wrong signals, etc.

I don't know where is my mistake in the code/logic...

Comment: We'll need to see some real code that reproduces the problem rather than an approximation.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong level of indirection in your calls to `receive_array`

Also, the argument type is wrong.

And, the setting of `current` is incorrect.

---

Your code was very incomplete. But, I was able to deduce an equivalent test program with the necessary corrections.

In the relevant sections, I demarcated old code vs. new code with `cpp` conditionals:

```
#if 0
// old code
#else
// new code
#endif
```

I also added [missing] setup and printing code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct strXP {
    int x;
    int y;
} strXP;

int value = 1;

#define SETSTR(_sym) \
    setstr(&_sym,#_sym)

void
setstr(strXP *ptr,const char *sym)
{
    ptr->x = value++;
    ptr->y = value++;
    ptr->y += 1000;

    printf("%s: ptr=%p x=%d y=%d\n",sym,ptr,ptr->x,ptr->y);
}

struct strXP A_01;
struct strXP A_02;
struct strXP A_03;
struct strXP A_04;

/*structs declared as extern in header file */
void
setA(void)
{
    SETSTR(A_01);
    SETSTR(A_02);
    SETSTR(A_03);
    SETSTR(A_04);
}

struct strXP B_01;
struct strXP B_02;
struct strXP B_03;
struct strXP B_04;

/* structs declared as extern in header file */
void
setB(void)
{
    SETSTR(B_01);
    SETSTR(B_02);
    SETSTR(B_03);
    SETSTR(B_04);
}

strXP *arr_01[4] = { &A_01, &A_02, &B_01, &B_02 };
strXP *arr_02[4] = { &A_03, &A_04, &B_03, &B_04 };

#if 0
void
receive_array(strXP arr_received[], int size)
#else
void
receive_array(strXP *arr_received[], int size)
#endif
{

    printf("receive_array:\n");

    for (int io = 0; io < size; io++) {
#if 0
        strXP *const current = &arr_received[io];
#else
        strXP *const current = arr_received[io];
#endif
        printf("  %p %d,%d\n", current, current->x, current->y);
    }
}

int
main(void)
{

    setA();
    setB();

#if 0
    receive_array(*arr_01, 4);
#else
    receive_array(arr_01, 4);
    receive_array(arr_02, 4);
#endif

    return 0;
}
```

---

Here's the program output:

```
A_01: ptr=0x4040f0 x=1 y=1002
A_02: ptr=0x4040c8 x=3 y=1004
A_03: ptr=0x4040f8 x=5 y=1006
A_04: ptr=0x4040d0 x=7 y=1008
B_01: ptr=0x4040e8 x=9 y=1010
B_02: ptr=0x4040d8 x=11 y=1012
B_03: ptr=0x404100 x=13 y=1014
B_04: ptr=0x4040e0 x=15 y=1016
receive_array:
  0x4040f0 1,1002
  0x4040c8 3,1004
  0x4040e8 9,1010
  0x4040d8 11,1012
receive_array:
  0x4040f8 5,1006
  0x4040d0 7,1008
  0x404100 13,1014
  0x4040e0 15,1016
```